# Why use apply in an UnderscoreJS-enabled rename function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

I am reading [Functional Javascript](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028857.do), which relies heavily on [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) for its examples. One example, in particular, is confusing to me. The author uses apply within a function twice: firtst, to concatenate an object and an array into an arguments array, and second to use an Underscore function on that array. The underscore function takes the two parameters that were concatenated, though, so it seems like an unnecessary extra step.

Here is the code in question:

```
function rename(obj, newNames) {
    return _.reduce(newNames, function(o, nu, old) {
        if (_.has(obj, old)) {
            o[nu] = obj[old];
        }
        return o;
    }, _.omit.apply(null, [].concat.apply(obj, _.keys(newNames))));
};

function rename2(obj, newNames) {
    return _.reduce(newNames, function(o, nu, old) {
        if (_.has(obj, old)) {
            o[nu] = obj[old];
        }
        return o;
    }, _.omit(obj, _.keys(newNames))); // Omitting the apply calls works fine
};

var source = {a: 1, b: 2},
    dictionary = {'a': 'AAA'};

rename(source, dictionary); // Object {a: "AAA"}
rename2(source, dictionary); // Object {a: "AAA"}
```

What is the reasoning behind using apply in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [Underscore docs for `omit`](http://underscorejs.org/#omit)! You can see that it <s>does not take an array as its second parameter, but</s> rather takes multiple parameters. Valid invocations would be

```
_.omit({…}, "a")
_.omit({…}, "a", "b")
_.omit({…}, "a", "b", …, "z")
```

Also have a look at the [code of `_.omit`](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-84).

<s>So why does your second invocation work at all? Because the one-element array (`['a']`) that you're passing in gets stringified and yields the expected property name.</s>

But how can you call `omit` with variable arguments? Especially, `_.keys(newNames)` does yield differently sized arrays. And this is just where [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is required.

---

At least, that's what the author intended to do.

Yet, I stand corrected. If we actually look at the source code, we can see the line

> ```
> var keys = concat.apply(ArrayProto, slice.call(arguments, 1));
> ```

So, by using [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) it allows the user to supply a variable amout of strings or arrays of strings. This means you're right, and using `apply` is just overly complicated.

Comment: That sounds right, but the description says: "Return a copy of the object, filtered to omit the blacklisted keys (or array of keys)." So, it should take an array, too, right?

It looks like it takes either an array or several arguments and produces an array of keys. It then checks each property against that array, and copies only the properties not contained in it.

I still do not see the difference. Can you expand on your explanation?

Comment: Ooops. I only checked the signature, where `*keys` meant a variable amout of parameters. The code allows for arrays as well. See updated answer.

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks for letting me know. Maybe they changed that method after he wrote the book?

Comment: Hm, no, it did work with an array in mid 2013 as well.

Comment: Must just be an oversight, then. I will check the errata for the book and submit it if it is not there already. Thanks for your help!